# Logical && and II operation with integer in Java

Tags: java, logical-operators

I have understood reading some problems here about the logical operation in Java. In Java, the whole operation is concentrating on boolean values, unlike C/C++. In C++,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=1, j= 1, k=0,m;
    m= ++i || ++j && ++k ;
    cout<<m;
    return 0;
}
```

I just wanted to learn how can I write this program in Java so that I can get the expected result.

Comment: `||` always is a boolean operator, but `|` isn't and probably is what you're looking for. Search for "java binary operators". N.b. : `|` can also be a boolean operator depending on context. But when its operands are numbers, it's the binary OR operator

Comment: 1. What is the "expected result"? 2. Why does getting this result in Java require using boolean operators on integers?

Comment: "_...how can I write this program in..._" You probably _shouldn't_ write this program in _any_ language. Too easy for someone reading it (including yourself in 6 months time) to get confused over whether `j`/`k` get incremented or not due to short-circuit evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

To conserve the short-circiuting behavior of the operators, you can split them into if statements:

```
int main()
{
  int i = 1, j = 1, k = 0, m;
  ++i;
  if (i == 0) {
    ++j;
    if (j != 0) {
      ++k;
      if (k == 0) {
        m = 0;
      } else {
        m = 1;
      }
    } else {
      m = 0
    }
  } else {
    m = 1;
  }
  System.out.print(m);
  return 0;
}
```

Another possibility would be to convert the integers into booleans (in C++ 0 coerces to false and every other value to true) in each step and eventually convert the final boolean back to 0 or 1. It is at least as unreadable as the nested if statements above:

```
int main() { 
  int i = 1, j = 1, k = 0, m;
  m = ((++i != 0) || (++j != 0) && (++k != 0)) ? 1 : 0;
  System.out.print(m);
  return 0;
}
```

But since all your numbers are constants, the simplest (and most readable) solution is to pre-compute the value:

```
int main() {
  System.out.println(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice answer, you just need to correct the precomputed solution. The result is 2, not 1.

Comment: @DDomen Why would it be 2? It is a boolean expression, which evaluates to true or false. Assigning a boolean expression to an int converts the value to 1 or 0, respectively. I have compiled the example locally to confirm, and yes, the output is `1` (not 2)

Comment: sorry you are right, I though `i` was printed in the original code. Nevermind... Note that in c/c++ the result could actually be `2` depending on compiler by the way

Comment: Probably the best translation of something like `++i || ++j && ++k` would be something like `(++i != 0 ? i : (++j != 0 && ++k != 0 ? k : 0))`

Comment: @DDomen no, it wouldn't, because now the result is an `int` and no longer a `boolean`. The C++ only has two possible result values: 0 and 1. Your suggested "transformation" can evaluate to any number from the range of integers (INT_MIN..INT_MAX). This is C++, not JavaScript or Python.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no direct equivalent, because in C/C++ `0` is `false`, `true` otherwise whereas Java is strongly typed; in Java you can’t cast an `int` to a `boolean`.

In Java, you have to do the “casts” from `int` to `boolean` and back again with code:

```
m = (++i != 0) || (++j != 0) && (++k != 0) ? 1 : 0;
```

---

You can use the bitwise operators `|` and `&`:

```
m = ++i | ++j & ++k; // valid java, result 2
```

but it’s semantically different.

Comment: "*you can use the bitwise operators | and &*" however, that will perform bitwise arithmetic and not logical operations: for `i=1, j= 3, k=6` the result is `6`, for example.

Comment: Bitwise operators will evaluate all operands, which can leave `j` and `k` with different values than the original code